# How to convert A4 size invoice to POS size invoice in blazor server

Tags: posprinter

I am working on a web app built in asp.net core that generates A4 size invoices(using blazor server), but now I am required to convert those invoices to POS invoices (which will print on thermal printer, like in the supermarkets). Also, A4 page has a fixed height but POS invoice should have a dynamic height according to the rows of data.

I have already tried adjusting the size values according to thermal paper but it just messes things up. And Invoice print format shows like a4 size but CSS as POS in full page width.

Is there any way to convert A4 size invoices to POS invoices? OR any way to generate POS invoices Blazor server

PS: POS thermal paper has a width of 80mm

I try to change style as POS but It shows this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kNAo.jpg)